# Some content lost while parsing string to xml

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-parsing

I have got some HTML code through AJAX responseText, which is 350-400 lines long. It has been stored in the variable `text` as string and I would like to parse it to XML. However, some of the content is removed while parsing. The result ends in the `script` part and none of the `body` part of the code can be seen.

```js
var xml = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(text, "text/xml");
alert(xml.querySelector("body"));
console.log(text);
console.log((new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xml));
```

For the result of `console.log(text)`, it returns the full code.

But The result of `console.log((new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xml))` returns a very incomplete one, which ends like that:

```
for (i = 0; i </script></head></html>
```

And the alert one shows `null`, so I'm pretty sure that the content has lost since the parsing process.

Can anyone tell me how to solve it?

Comment: Does the script contain xml-unsafe characters... like `if (a < b && b > c )`?

Comment: Looking at `i = 0; i`... I guess it does. HTML is not valid XML.

Comment: The `for` statement actually should be `for (i = 0; i < xml.scripts.length; i++) `. The whole script is between <script> and </script>. Isn't it just regarded as innerXML text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML isn't always valid XML. From your partial output it appears that you are trying to parse HTML. In that case, you should change the second parameter of `parseFromString` to `"text/html"` instead of `"text/xml"`. After this the XML serialization should work fine.

Additionally, to get the serialized string you can also access the property `documentElement.outerHTML` on Document object returned from `parseFromString` method.